# CakePHP blog tutorial - Cannot redeclare UsersController::beforeFilter()

Tags: php, cakephp

Why does it give me this error, I checked all the code and i'm hoping there aren't dumb mistakes. The login page is meant to display.

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare UsersController::beforeFilter() in C:\wamp\www\dale-blog\app\Controller\UsersController.php on line 64

```
 //line 63:
    public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('add'); //Letting users register themselves
    }
```

Comment: It means `Cannot redeclare UsersController::beforeFilter()` !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you have declared `public function beforeFilter()` twice in the same controller.

Comment: But the tutorial tells me to do that exact thing

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Comment: you probably misunderstood it

Comment: Dale - it doesn't show `public function beforeFilter() {` twice.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with cakephp, but I can assure you the message implies the said function (beforeFilter) has been previously declared. Do a search for the offending duplicate and zap it out.

Happy caking, cheers

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Comment: Yes, my friend. I don't have to read anything to tell you I am 100% sure that your function is declared twice. The error message is clear enough and applies to all PHP code, Cake-centric or not. Search for 'function beforeFilter', without the visibility identifier (public).  Make sure you search or 'grep' through the whole application code, as they can easily be in separate files/includes.  Good-luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same 'mistake'. It was because the tutorial tells you that you must to code twice but it must be clear that the line that has to be *modified*  not *added* is

```
public function beforeFilter(){
        $this->Auth->allow('index','view');
    }
```

in the AppController.php File